# Can't connect to google play service

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I had an android application working fine in all average smartphones, but only one client is using a custom phone from Huawei, he received this error `Can't connect to google play service`, and also `Google Maps` not working, so my question there's any way **programmatically** to send a request to download the missed google play service ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't install Google Play Services like a normal application, since it isn't a normal application. It's actually at least 3.

It needs to be a system app (ie in `/system/priv-app/`) to work, and relies on certain other frameworks that can't simply be installed.

If this user is rooted, tell them to flash Google Play Services from something like OpenGApps or MicroG. Otherwise, if you need people without Google Services to use your app, you need to find another maps API that isn't from Google.

Comment: Thak's, no, it's not rooted, so if I send him apk of google play service to install will resolve the issue ? it's my first time with a simillar situation, so I'm really confused.
Another question do you know any maps API not from Google ?

Comment: @StanlyEl like I said in my answer, you can't just install them like a normal app. Unfortunately I don't know of any.

Comment: for future, this is maps API :

- http://geoawesomeness.com/google-maps-api-alternatives-best-cheap-affordable/